# Race condition in JavaScript with onload event

Tags: javascript

Let's say I'm loading a page that contains this code:

```
<script>
    function functionAlert() {
        alert(window.myProperty);
    }

    function functionSetProperty() {
        window.myProperty = "hello!";
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', functionAlert, false);
    functionSetProperty();
</script>
```

Is the race condition possible that `functionAlert` gets called before `functionSetProperty`, in which case the alert will show `undefined`?

Comment: Why you don't switch the window.addEventListener line with the functionSetProperty function? Then you got what you want. But i think it is better to design another method.

Comment: What do you mean, "get what you want"? The question wasn't meant to achieve a programming goal. I wanted to learn something about how window events and JavaScript work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  Browser-based JavaScript is single-threaded and blocks the browser from processing events while it is executing.

(I've seen some exceptions to this in the wild, but they've all centered around XmlHttpRequest.)